# How do I ensure that viewDidLoad is called without warning?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

```
BGLogin * login = [[BGLogin alloc]init];

[nav pushViewController:login animated:YES];
login.view; //access it once to trigger didload
NSAssert(login.navigationItem==login.navigationItemAtDidload,@"They should be the same");//View didload isn't called yet here.
NSAssert(login.navigationController == nav,@"The navigation controller should be the same");
NSAssert(nav.navigationBar.topItem==login.navigationItem,@"We just push our self so our stuff should be on top");
```

It's simple code. However if I do not do login.view then viewDidLoad will not be called first. If I do login.view than I got a warning that value of login.view is not used.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the return value, then don't use the property accessor syntax (`login.view`). Call the getter like a regular method: `[login view]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want use `login.view;` to make the `viewDidLoad` be called , I think you had better to add some code in your `BGLogin` classs `init` method.

such as :

```
- (id)init
{
    // your code

    self.view.tag = 0;
    return self;
}
```

or you can change your `login.view;` to `login.view.tag = 0;`

it will call the `viewDidLoad` , but I do not think it is better , but it will work for you , maybe somebody has a better way to handle it

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't the answer appropriate? If you downvote, at least comment, so that I can improve the post.